# Какие есть библиотеки на чистом си для чтения bmp файлов?

Tags: c

Подскажите маленькую хорошую библиотеку для работы с различными bmp файлами именно для си.

Comment: Первой строкой поиска гугл выдаёт: [libbmp](https://github.com/marc-q/libbmp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классический вариант: [**stb_image**](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h).

- Умеет грузить bmp, png, jpeg, tga и еще несколько форматов.
- Проста в использовании - за один вызов функции открывает файл и получает из него массив цветов пикселей.
- Умещается в один файл и не использует никакие другие библиотеки.
- Public domain - нет никаких ограничений на ее использование.